# ntfsclone, metadata-only cloning....why?

Tags: cloning, ntfs-3g, file-metadata

Been reading the ntfsclone [manual](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-ntfsclone/) but I still can understand and see the point of doing a Metadata-only cloning? What is the point of this, when can it be valuable?
I assume "metadata" is just information about the filesystem objects (e.g. folder and files) but not the objects themself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be useful to recover from filesystem corruption.

When you format c:, or delete files by accident, the metadata is what you lose first and without metadata, it's a very difficult process to restore / undelete / recover individual files or entire filesystems.

However, it would be easy if you had a metadata clone. It instantly gives you an intact mountable filesystem. As for the contents, they would still be there, if they were not overwritten/discarded in the incident and not relocated since the metadata backup was made.

Of course, it's still much better to have a real backup (metadata+contents) that survives drive failures and the like.

Comment: I would guess that the metadata-only cloning perhaps originated as a NTFS filesystem driver development tool, as it would be very useful for a developer to have the ability to perform some filesystem manipulation, save the metadata, then roll the filesystem back (perhaps by regular disk/partition imaging), and then perform the same manipulation using native Windows, save the metadata again, and then compare the metadata sets in a nice, compact form.

Comment: Good to be confirmed that there is nothing more to it than that. Really not useful in  my real-life use-cases

Comment: It is very much a real-life use-case though (cause in real-life people don't have backups). Undeletion comes up all the time. Tons of effort go into tools like `photorec`, and it exactly plays the guessing-game: what's this file? how large was it? what was its filename? where are its other blocks located? None of this would be necessary with metadata backups, which no one ever bothers to make. And then SSDs come in and just discard all deleted data anyway, making recovery impossible, for the sake of better benchmark scores.